# How do I add emojis into coding projects like Xcode in Mac?

Tags: xcode, emoji

I have just started to use Xcode in my Mac, so I am pretty new. I know the basics but I don't know how to code icons into my script. For example, I namely want to add a thumbs up emoji, or a smile, but I really don't know how to really code that.

I have tried adding "", "thumbsup.fill" and I looked into other comments and tried their things, but it doesn't seem to work. all I see is a blank screen.

Anybody got suggestions?

Comment: Are you using UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: I am using SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an imageview and add the following code :

```
Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup.fill")
 .resizable()
 .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
 .frame(width: 25.0, height: 25.0, alignment: .center)
```